# Getting null from room database sum query, with data available

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have two functions in my dao

```
    @Query("select sum(amount) as sum, dateString from databasetransaction where txnType='A' group by dateString")
    fun getExpensesTransaction(): LiveData<List<TxnByDate>>

    @Query("select COALESCE(sum(COALESCE(amount,0)), 0) from databasetransaction")
    fun getTotal() : LiveData<Int>
```

For first query I am getting data with object

```
{
  sum:2000,
  dateString:"04/10/2019"
}
```

For 2nd query I am getting null as value, can some one help me, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue may not really be with the query as such but rather handling of the result and placing it into a Int.

I don't believe that you need COALESCE at all, certainly not two occurrences, as the **total** aggregate function differs from the **sum** function in that it does not return **null**,  as per :-

> The sum() and total() aggregate functions return sum of all non-NULL values in the group. If there are no non-NULL input rows then sum() returns NULL but total() returns 0.0. [sum(X) total(X)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc)

The result in the above is what I suspect is happening. You get a floating point with a decimal point, that then cannot be converted to an Int and that null is returned.

You could try using :-

```
SELECT CAST(total(amount) AS INTEGER) from databasetransaction;
```

Comment: solved it, it was actually issue with my viewmodel, I was not using the variable which was getting results from the 2nd query, and as a result, it was null, as soon as I put observer on it or did data binding it started working

Comment: can you add your view model class. Because I am also facing the same issue.